# EnTT: Creating new component-types at runtime, or "tagging" a subgroup of entities?

Tags: c++, game-development, entity-component-system

I'm working in a group project on a small 2D minecraft-like game, applying the [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) design pattern. We're **required** to use the [EnTT framework](https://github.com/skypjack/entt).

We'd like to make it easier to manage blocks by tagging blocks as "belonging" to the chunk they're in, so that we could just do something like

```
registry.view<Block, ChunkID>();
```

to grab all the blocks in a given chunk from the registry enmasse.

Is there a way to dynamically create new components in EnTT? Or to tag a set of entities as being part of a larger group, then retrieve all the entities in that group?

Also, is there a way we could manage EnTT IDs manually in a specific registry?

Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested to [this](https://github.com/skypjack/entt/issues/607) issue. :)